# Make a 1 item array be seen as an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently working on a php project where I am trying to loop through an array using a foreach. However, sometimes the array may only contain 1 item so when I try and do a foreach it fails as 1 item is just seen as a normal variable.

Is there a way that I can trick php into thinking that a 1 item array is actually an array and not just a variable so that I don't get this error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: array with one item IS an array, and there is no tricking required

Comment: An array with one item is still an array, and can be looped using foreach(). If you've found that this isn't the case, please provide a working example to demonstrate your problem

Comment: what code using foreach() fails on an array with 1 item, never seen that before

Answer (score 5):

`foreach` will work fine with arrays of size 0,1 or bigger. I suspect your problem is, that the variable doesn't really contain an array, but some scalar value - in this case use something like

```
if (!is_array($var)) $var=array($var);
foreach ($var as $item) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($arr))
    $arr2=$arr
else
    $arr2=array($arr)
```

and then you iterate over `$arr2`

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend just using a standard for loop.  It should work no matter what the length of the array is

```
for($i = 0, $l = count($myArray); $i < $l; $i+=1){
  //code in here
}
```

But chances are you have an issue with your array to begin.  Posting the structure would be helpful, or you should var_dump it to make sure it is indeed an array.

Comment: downvotes with no comments?  Because I suggested for instead of foreach?

Comment: I suspect you got downvoted because it should not make a difference. There is no problem with `foreach()`.